# How to correctly convert "Exit with shortcut" action to the latest working version?

Tags: homekit

I simply tried to apply rules from the following article:

[Motion sensors with HomeKit: How to turn off lights after a certain time?](https://patrikmojzis.medium.com/motion-sensors-with-homekit-how-to-turn-off-lights-after-a-certain-time-a9b616b719ae)

[image]

And this is my **❌ not working** result:

[image]

Simply my lights are not turned off: `Kuchnia Noc` > `Kitchen Night`

Is it correct way to replace `Exit shortcut with` action?